S3 bucket cross region replication
Hell,
My goal is to setup S3 CRR between VA and OH. My code runs without any errors, however encrypted objects arn't replicated to the destination bucket after running terraform apply.
I took it for granted it was an AWS problem and created a ticket for it. That was when I was told encrypted objects aren't being replicated. I had to add the destination key arn manually in the console, even though I had it in Terraform code as below. I don't know why I have to go in mnaully after the fact(terraform apply) to enable replication of encrypted objects. If anyone can spare some ideas, its really a strange problem to have. Thank you very much.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.47.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region[0]
  alias  = "source"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region[1]
  alias  = "dest"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "replication_role" {
  provider = aws.source

  name        = "${var.bucket_name[0]}-rep-role"
  description = "IAM role source bucket replication."

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode(
    {
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {
          Effect = "Allow"
          Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
          Principal = {
            Service = "s3.amazonaws.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  )

  tags = local.project_tags
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "replication_policy" {
  provider = aws.source

  name = "${aws_s3_bucket.source_bucket.bucket}-rep-policy"
  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" = "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" = [
        {
          "Action" = [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:GetObjectRetention",
            "s3:GetObjectLegalHold"
          ],
          "Effect" = "Allow",
          "Resource" = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name[0]}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name[0]}/*"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Action" = [
            "s3:ReplicateObject",
            "s3:ReplicateDelete",
            "s3:ReplicateTags",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
          ],
          "Effect" = "Allow",
          "Condition" = {
            "StringLikeIfExists": {
              "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                "aws:kms",
                "aws:kms:dsse",
                "AES256"
              ]
            }
          },
          "Resource" = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name[1]}/*"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Action" = [
            "kms:Decrypt"
          ],
          "Effect" = "Allow",
          "Condition" = {
            "StringLike" = {
              "kms:ViaService" = "s3.${var.region[0]}.amazonaws.com",
              "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn" = [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name[0]}"
              ]
            }
          },
          "Resource" = [
            "arn:aws:kms:${var.region[0]}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:key/${aws_kms_key.source_key.id}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Action" = [
            "kms:Encrypt"
          ],
          "Effect" = "Allow",
          "Condition" = {
            "StringLike" = {
              "kms:ViaService" = [
                "s3.${var.region[1]}.amazonaws.com"
              ],
              "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn" = [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name[1]}"
              ]
            }
          },
          "Resource" = [
            "arn:aws:kms:${var.region[1]}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:key/${aws_kms_key.dest_key.id}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  )

  depends_on = [aws_iam_role.replication_role]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role_policy_attach" {
  provider = aws.source

  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.replication_policy.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.replication_role.name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "source_bucket_replication" {
  provider = aws.source

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.source_bucket.bucket
  role   = aws_iam_role.replication_role.arn

  rule {
    status = "Enabled"
    destination {
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
      bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.dest_bucket.arn
    }
  }

  depends_on = [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.role_policy_attach]
}


In the aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration you didn't place the encryption_configuration field, where you need to add the kms key id
rule {
    status = "Enabled"
    destination {
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
      bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.dest_bucket.arn

      encryption_configuration {
        replica_kms_key_id = aws_kms_key.dest_key.arn  
      }
    }
  }

If replica_kms_key_id is not specified in the replication configuration, I think S3 will fail to replicate these objects, as it won’t know how to encrypt them in the destination bucket.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_replication_configuration#destination

Thank you Sir, it explains quite a bit, I will amend my code and try another run.

Hope you accept the answer when it works
